# need to sort, filter and set default value using rxjs

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an observable in angular application which is bound to the reactive forms dropdown control. I basically need to filter, sort and also show the default value. I have written two implementations where the the first one does the filtering and sorting but not the default value while the latter does the default value only. I am able to merge them together and get it to work but not sure if it is the best way. Can anybody give some insight into this please

```
 this.nameList$ = this.nameService.getNames()
      .pipe(
        map(response => response
           .filter(t =>
            t.name !== '!',
          )
          .sort(this.sortByNameAscending),

        ),
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      )


      this.nameList$ = this.nameService.getNames()
      .pipe(
        tap((values: any) => {
          const found = values.find(x => x.isDefault);
          if (found) {
            this.form.get('firstName').setValue(found.name);
          }
      
  
        })
       
        ,
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      )
```

I have tried this which works but not sure if it is the best way to do it

```
 this.nameList$ = this.nameService.getTitles()
      .pipe(
        map(response => response
           .filter(t =>
            t.name !== '!',
          )
          .sort(this.sortByNameAscending),

        ),
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      )
      .pipe(
        tap((response: any) => {
          const found = response.find(x => x.isDefault);
          if (found) {
            this.form.get('firstName').setValue(found.name);
          }
      
  
        })
       
        ,
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      )
```

Comment: I started writing a comment when you updated the question. Yes, what you have is correct but you don't need another pipe. Move the tap from the second pipe to the first. So it will look like this: `this.nameList$ = this.nameService.getTitles().pipe(map(...), tap(...), takeUntil(...))`

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer this:

```
this.nameList$ = this.nameService.getNames().pipe(share(), takeUntil(this.destroy$))
this.nameList$.subscribe(() => ...)
this.nameList$.subscribe(() => ...)
```